# Class 'Radcodes_Lib_Validate_License' not found

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

> Class 'Radcodes_Lib_Validate_License' not found
>   /home/XXXX/public_html/application/modules/Videofeed/Form/Admin/Global.php
>   on line 35

```
$this->addElement('Text', 'videofeed_license', array(
      'label' => 'Video Feed License Key',
      'description' => 'Enter the your license key that is provided to you when you purchased this plugin. If you do not know your license key, please contact Radcodes support team.',
      'value' => Engine_Api::_()->getApi('settings', 'core')->getSetting('videofeed.license', 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'),
      'filters' => array(
        'StringTrim'
      ),
      'allowEmpty' => false,
      'validators' => array(
        new Radcodes_Lib_Validate_License('videofeeds'),
      ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your lib files in the library or add you lib files path to the include path defined in index.php

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your lib (Radcodes) files in the library or add you lib files path to the include path defined in index.php